# Joining two tables by ID SQL

Tags: sql

I have researched online but I'm unable to get my head around the subject. 
I have two tables from my database "username" and "password". Table **username** includes columns "id" and "username" table **password** includes "id" and password. I understand this may be relatively straight forward but I've tried to no avail. Is it possible to join them by id so I can see id:username:password ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Apparently, you already know that you need to use `JOIN`. What is the problem then?

Comment: That seems like an odd design. Is the max id in username and password the same? What about the count? Is it the same for both tables? If so, then you might be able to join them by id and I can help you with that. If not then it might not be correct to join them using ID.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD
FROM USERNAME, PASSWORD
WHERE USERNAME.ID = PASSWORD.ID;
```

It would be something like this. For your specific database, look up the topic regarding JOINS, CROSS JOINS, etc.